# extract data from an .osm.pbf file within python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

I've downloaded the great britain .osm.pbf file from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html and I want to be able to pull out all the lat and lons of every node. is this possible?

If i could get it into python format of some sort that would be great

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pyosmium](https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/) to parse an .osm.pbf file.

This simple example just prints the location and name of every node that has a [name tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name):

```
import osmium
import sys

class NamesHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    def node(self, n):
        if 'name' in n.tags:
            print(f'{n.location}: ' + n.tags['name'])

def main(osmfile):
    NamesHandler().apply_file(osmfile)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python %s <osmfile>" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(-1)

    exit(main(sys.argv[1]))
```

Of course, you'll probably want to do something more sophisticated with the data depending on your use case. Check the [documentation](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/) for a basic usage tutorial and reference, and the README of the [pyosmium GitHub repository](https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium) for installation instructions.

Comment: Where would I put the file location in to here?

Comment: @DRobins With this small example script, the file is provided as a command line parameter. It's taken from sys.argv[1] in the final line, passed to main, and finally passed to the handler's apply_file. Only that last step is specific to pyosmium, the rest is just there so that the example script can be executed.